# Website seems to know location / Orbot & Orfox

Tags: configuration, anonymity, android

I have been using orbot/orfox on an android/cyanogen tablet. However, a website seems to still know my location. I would like to prevent this, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I am not torifying apps, only using orfox. I will start a new orbot session, then check the browser, which shows a different IP. Then I visit the site using a private tab. After this I clear the browser data. The next time I visit, I follow the same procedure. However, the site remembers my location (like town, not just nation). I haven't whitelisted the site in NoScript. I clear the data on in orfox regularly. I don't mix modes of anonymity.

Can the site be storing something on my device to ID me? If so, is there a way to remove this and prevent its recurrence? Or is there some sort of personal info I might be leaking?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you give an example of a site to reproduce this?